# Get Firestore collection and sub-collection document data together

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Firestore database structure in my Ionic 5 app.

- Book(collection)

  - {bookID}(document with book fields)

    - Like (sub-collection)

      - {userID} (document name as user ID with fields)

`Book` collection has documentes and each document has a `Like` sub-collection. The document names of Like collection are user IDs who liked the book.

I am trying to do a query to get the latest `books` and at the same time trying to get the document from `Like` sub-collection to check if I have liked it.

```
async getBook(coll) {
  snap = await this.afs.collection('Book').ref
    .orderBy('createdDate', "desc")
    .limit(10).get();

  snap.docs.map(x => {
    const data = x.data();
    coll.push({
      key: x.id,
      data: data.data(),
      like: this.getMyReaction(x.id)
    });
  }

async getMyReaction(key) {
    const res = await this.afs.doc('Book/myUserID').ref.get();
    if(res.exists) {
    return res.data();
  } else {
    return 'notFound';
  }
}
```

What I am doing here is calling the method `getMyReaction()` with each book ID and storing the promise in the `like` field.  Later, I am reading the `like` value with `async` pipe in the HTML. This code is working perfectly but there is a little delay to get the `like` value as the promise is taking time to get resolved. Is there a solution to get sub-collection value at the same time I am getting the collection value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a solution to get sub-collection value at the same time I am getting the collection value?

Not without restructuring your data.  Firestore queries can only consider documents in a single collection.  The only exception to that is collection group queries, which lets you consider documents among all collections with the exact same name.  What you're doing right now to "join" these two collections is probably about as effective as you'll get.

The only way you can turn this into a single query is by having another collection with the data pre-merged from the other two collections.  This is actually kind of common on nosql databases, and is referred to as denormalization.  But it's entirely up to you to decide if that's right for your use case.